# Text box cursor manipulation

Tags: vb.net

I had quite a bit of luck yesterday finding a solution to my problem, so I've come up with a new one.

My program is a multi-tab calculator, and for the user inputs I am aiming for full keyboard navigation.  I have my boxes laid out in a grid, and have keydown subs for each box that trap the arrow keys, allowing the user to navigate between the boxes using arrows.

The flaw I find in this, is if I input something into the boxes and make a mistake (during runtime), I either have to backspace x number of times and retype, or click the cursor into position to change a single character. I am quickly seeing the need to use left and right arrows to navigate cursor position within the textboxes, but would like to retain some of the navigation function.

So I have a few questions based off of this.

Is there a way to detect cursor position in a text control?
If so, is said cursor position numeric? i.e. position = 0 at the start of the box, position = 1 between the first and second characters and so forth.

I am trying to write a sub that will count the characters in a string, decide if the cursor is on the left or right of said string and then allow the appropriate move to the next box when it is.

```
Private Sub countCharacters()
  'I'm not sure of the syntax yet, I'm researching this currently, so please bear with 
  'me, I'm trying to get my concept across.

  Dim txtBoxCount As Integer
  txtBoxCount = txtBox1.Text.count '???

  Dim txtBoxPos As Integer
  txtBox1.cursor.position.get '???
End Sub

Private Sub onKeyDown()
  countCharacters()
  If e.KeyData = Keys.Left Then
     e.SuppressKeyPress = True  'As I'm typing this, I realize I might need to change this, but 
                                 'for now it is suppressing the beeps
     If txtBoxPos > 0 Then
        move cursor left within the box   '???

     Else if txtBoxPos = 0 Then
        nextBoxLeft.focus()
     End If
  End If

End Sub
```

Anyhow, I'm researching this, and will work to find my own answer.  Just hoping there might be someone out there who can shed some light onto if such a thing is possible, and if I'm even on the right track?

Be gentle, I'm self teaching and have been at this for only a few weeks.

Comment: *Cursor* is the mouse thingy, *Caret* is the blinking line thingy inside TextBoxes.

Comment: Aye, I've just recently figured that out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood how the controls are laid out on the form, but TextBox does have a property that tells you where the caret is, and it's called [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx).

Despite the name, it also works when no text is *actually* selected.

Oh, and you don't need to write a method to determine the length of a string: just use the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Since you're new, remember that strings can be `null` (or `Nothing` in VB parlance), so you need to check if that's the case before using `Length`. Generally speaking, the `Text` property won't be `null`, but you want to keep this in mind.

Comment: I'll start toying around with this.  I'll post more as I get more specific questions, or barring that, my solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jack I see you might be referring to that "move cursor left within the box". If that's the case, you can set the same SelectionStart property to a location you choose within the TextBox.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks.  So glad I found this site.  Can you see any pitfalls in the solution i've posted below based on your guidance?

Comment: @Jack looks good to me. Just do your fair amount of manual testing and see if there are funny corner cases you need to handle. UI bugs can be sneaky ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to s.m., I have found my solution.

```
   Private Sub TextBox3_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyDown
    Dim length As Integer
    length = TextBox3.TextLength
    Dim position As Integer
    position = TextBox3.SelectionStart
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Left Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True

        If position = 0 Then
            TextBox2.Focus()
        ElseIf position > 0 Then
            TextBox3.SelectionStart = (position - 1)
        End If
    End If
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If position = length Then
            TextBox1.Focus()
        ElseIf position < length Then
            TextBox3.SelectionStart = (position + 1)
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```